# Do i have to reject the binary uploaded?

Tags: ios, app-store

Today i have generated the distribution certificates and added this to application changed code-signing identity from development to distribution successfully and created the archive for uploading it the app store .

I clicked the validate button in the Organiser and uploaded the app successfully. But i have noticed that there is new provision profile with type development in the developer account genrated today .

it is possible that during validation the provision gets replaced from distribution to development?.

Please do suggest or let me know how can i check the provision profile being used in the binary uploaded to the app store .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Don't worry about it.

The fact that your app got successfully validated and was successfully uploaded to iTunes Connect means the binary should be good to go. You shouldn't have any issues. However, if your app status is "Invalid Binary", then it's very likely you have a codesigning problem. If it says "Waiting for Review", you're fine.

More info: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to worry about that. But if you want to verify than you can do one thing go to window -> organizer in XCode. Goto Archives in section Select your project find build which you submitted to store right click on it and show in finder. You can find xcarchive type file, right click to it and select show package content. Go in folder Products -> Applications in it your Application present again right click it and select show package content in that you find one file named embedded.mobileprovision that profile is used with that build. You can open it with text edit and find aps-environment production if it is of production.

Answer (score 3):

The validation for distribution and upload of binary would not have been successful without the distribution certificates, there is no way for the provisioning for the app to change to development after the app is sent for review. So nothing to worry the new provision generated (this is possibly automatically generated by Xcode for your next app)